# How to crop-rotate video

Tags: image-editing, video-editing, crop

How can I crop rotate a video, so that it crops and rotates at the same time. I know that there is an option for this in Photos.app, but it only works for photos. Is there some other application that can be used to do this?

Here is a gif of what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

**[EDIT]**

In case the above isn't clear, what I want to be able to do is:

- zoom **and** rotate the video, but only rotate it slightly (e.g. 10-15°) rather than 90° at a time, and
- also crop it so that the overall video is still square

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### FFmpeg

**Using FFmpeg from the `.dmg` image:**

Download from `https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/`, download the `.dmg` file
then use terminal to edit your files, with this command.

`cd` to the folder with the files.(type `cd <space>` then drag the folder to terminal)

for example `cd /Volumes/MacDATA/Users/he/Movies` press enter
- drag the ffmpeg(icon in black), and add the code behind.

```
`/Volumes/FFmpeg\ 87390-gd491d6a/ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex rotate=5*PI/180:ow='iw*0.85':oh='ih*0.85' output.mp4`
```

**Using the FFmpeg from brew**

Use [brew](https://brew.sh) and run `brew install ffmpeg`.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex rotate=5*PI/180:ow='iw*0.85':oh='ih*0.85' output.mp4`
```

---

*change the `input.mp4` and `output.mp4` your filename, change the `5` to your 'degree' for example `rotate=10*PI/180` and reduce the scale (`0.85` thing) to maybe `0.75` for `10` degree.*

Answer (score 2):

Final Cut Pro should be able to do this. That app is the Swiss army knife of video editing on Mac. You could animate a transform of your clip. First, in the Video inspector, open up the Transform controls and position your video how you want it to end up.

Here's [how to animate that transform](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12609?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US). You can set a keyframe for the beginning and ending positions of the clip, and Final Cut will animate the frames in between.

Final Cut Pro isn't free, but it does have a free 30-day trial. Just go [here](https://www.apple.com/final-cut-pro/trial/).

Comment: thank you for the answer! I did not give you the bounty, but I did upvote your answer because I think it is a good one. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the upvote, and glad you got it solved!